# UITextview SizetoFit Align RIGHT in UITableView

Tags: alignment, uitextview, scale

Quick question, any way to Align a UITextField that has Sizetofit enabled ?  say to the RIGHT ?

I have a chat conversation window(UITableView), and use the Sizetofit to help create those "bubble" type conversations for my actual Message  (picture=>[image: Picture of my Conversation Chat Window, where the UITextField, MessageLabel has size to fit, but does not align RIGHT, for the user who is currently signed in.]

any help would greatly be appreciated, getting those bubbles to the right :-)

Here is a barebones snippet....

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
MessageCustomCellCell *cell = (MessageCustomCellCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell.messageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
    cell.messageLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

NSSortDescriptor *ratingsSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedRows = [_tableData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ratingsSortDescriptor]];
_tableData = sortedRows;
NSDictionary *item = [_tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


 // loggedInUser
 if ([[item objectForKey:@"fromuser"] isEqualToString:loggedInUser]) {

    cell.messageLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"message"];
    cell.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 25, 246, cell.messageLabel.contentSize.height);
    [cell.messageLabel sizeToFit];

 } else {
 // MESSAGE IS FRIEND OF THE PERSON SIGNED IN
     cell.messageLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"message"];
     cell.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     cell.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(65, 25, 250, cell.messageLabel.contentSize.height);
     [cell.messageLabel sizeToFit];

 }
```

I guess one way would be to find out the actual width of the text, or count it, and adjust and position accordingly, but not to sure how.

THanks!

Comment: Hey, Knitsu! I'm trying to make a chat myself and have the same problem now. Have you solved it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

this is my example.

```
(void)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message {
    [self.messageView setText:message];
    self.messageView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.messageView sizeToFit];

    CGRect myFrame = self.messageView.frame;
    myFrame.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - myFrame.size.width;
    [self.messageView setFrame:myFrame];
}
```